# Insert a row and copy the formatting but only for certain columns

Tags: excel, vba, rows

I am using the following code to insert a row under the cell, when double clicked, and to copy the formatting and formula from above. However, I would like it to only copy the formulas and formatting from columns A:K.

I've tried a couple of different things but keep getting errors thrown up. I'm sure this would be an easy fix for someone out there, I'm just going round and round, how should I adjust my code? - please help

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = True
    Target.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
    Target.EntireRow.Copy Target.Offset(1).EntireRow
    On Error Resume Next
    Target.Offset(1).EntireRow.SpecialCells(xlConstants).ClearContents
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Target.Row = 1 Then Exit Sub

    Cancel = True

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With Target.Worksheet
        .Rows(Target.Row + 1).Insert (xlDown)

        .Rows(Target.Row + 1).Clear
        .Range("A" & Target.Row & ":K" & Target.Row).Copy

        With .Range("A" & Target.Row + 1 & ":K" & Target.Row + 1)
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas

            ' Remove this code here if you DON'T want to clear the cells
            ' that do not have formulas.
            On Error Resume Next
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
            On Error GoTo 0
        End With
    End With

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Target.Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

... if so, add error checking and any additional requirements and hopefully it's good to go.

Comment: Hi @Skin, unfortunately it doesn't. It doesn't copy the formatting or formula at all from the row above.

Comment: @Mr_Col, what about now?  Hopefully I've interpreted it correctly.

Comment: Hi @Skin, thanks for the update, however it still doesn't quite perform what I need. Perhaps my explanation is not clear enough. If I double click on a cell/row it inserts a row underneath but copies the formatting and formulas of that row that was initially double clicked i.e the row above the newly inserted one. My code at the moment copies the entire row above, I just want it to copy column A:K - hope that is clearer?

Comment: @Mr_Col, yep, I think that's clearer.  I went a row above the double click row.  Answer updated, 3rd time lucky?!?  Actually, next question, do cells A to K have a mix of formulas and values?  If so, I'll need to make another update.

Comment: That's the Badger!! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Mr_Col answer updated with a comment, take it or leave but looks like you got your answer.  Glad I could help and sorry for the iterations.  :-)